# Line Integral where C is a line segment

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question states to evaluate the integral $\int_C \ xe^{y} ds$ from $(-1,2)$ to $(1,1)$

After finding the parametric equations $x(t) = 2t+1$ and $y(t) = -t+2$, solving for $ds$, and substituting, I get $\int_0^1 \ (2t+1)e^{-t+2}\sqrt{5}\ dt$

It may seem trivial relative to the original problem but I am not sure how to integrate this properly (or if my integral is set up properly for that matter). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it help to note that $\int te^{-t} dt = -e^{-t}(t+1)$?

Comment: I suggest expanding the expression to get $\sqrt{5}\left(2\int_0^1te^{2-t}\,\mathrm dt+\int_0^1e^{2-t}\,\mathrm dt\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x,y)\in \overline{(-1,2) (1,1)}$ is going to be $(x,y)=(2t-1,2-t), t\in [0,1]$

$\begin{align}
\int_C xe^y\;\operatorname{d}s & =\sqrt 5 \int_0^1 (2t-1)e^{2-t}\operatorname{d}t 
\\ & = \sqrt 5 \int_{-2}^{-1} (2u-5) e^{-u} \operatorname{d}u & \text{ where } u=t-2\end{align}$

Now use: $(-e^{-u})' = e^{-u}$ and $(-(u+1)e^{-u})' = ue^{-u}$

(That is: $\int e^{-u}\operatorname{d}u = -e^{-u}+\text{constant},\quad \int ue^{-u}\operatorname{d} u = -(u+1)e^{-u}+\text{constant}$)

Comment: So what exactly would I do with the 2 and 3 in $(2u+3)$ since the $2u$ doesn't match up with the $-u$ exponent and the +3 doesn't match with the equation you listed at the bottom

Comment: @Coop : $\int (2u+3)e^{-u}\operatorname{d}u = 2\int ue^{-u}\operatorname{d}u + 3\int e^{-u}\operatorname{d}u$

Comment: You could also write the exponent as $ \ -(t - 2) \ = \ -( \ [t - \frac{1}{2}] - \frac{3}{2} \ ) \ $ , and use $ \ u \ = \ t - \frac{1}{2} \ $ , so that the integrand becomes $ \ 2u \ e^{-u} \ e^{3/2} \ \sqrt{5} \ $ .  Now three numerical factors can be removed to outside the integral and there is only one function to integrate.

Comment: @GrahamKemp should it be $(2u-3)$?